# Using node icons in Vaadin Flow / 14 TreeGrid component

Tags: treeview, vaadin, vaadin-flow

Example (VueJs / [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview/)) i want to achieve:

[image]

Vaadin only has `TreeGrid#addHierarchyColumn(ValueProvider)` which does not allow adding icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [feature](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid-flow/pull/789) is not yet in the Vaadin 14 framework, but it has just been actually implemented and is coming to the next minor version, i.e 14.2

Meanwhile it is possible to have [a workaround using Template renderer](https://github.com/TatuLund/filesystem-dataprovider-flow/blob/master/src/main/java/org/vaadin/filesystemdataprovider/FileSelect.java#L59), like I have done it in my [FileSelect](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/filesystem-dataprovider-add-on) component.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answer of Tatu Lund we baked our own version, tested with Vaadin 14.1.23

```
/**
 * {@code IconTreeGrid} adds a convenience method for a `TreeGrid` with node icons.
 *
 * Based on these answers:
 *
 * + https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17625675/treegrid-displaying-icon-for-hierachy-column
 * + https://stackoverflow.com/a/61268891/868941
 */
static class IconTreeGrid<T> extends TreeGrid<T> {

    IconTreeGrid(HierarchicalDataProvider<T, ?> dataProvider) {
        super(dataProvider);
    }

    public Column<T> addHierarchyColumn(Icon icon, ValueProvider<T, ?> valueProvider) {
        final Column<T> column = addColumn(TemplateRenderer.<T>of(
            "<vaadin-grid-tree-toggle leaf='[[item.leaf]]' expanded='{{expanded}}' level='[[level]]'>" +
            "<iron-icon icon='[[item.icon]]' style='margin-right: 0.2em; [[item.style]]'></iron-icon>[[item.name]]" +
            "</vaadin-grid-tree-toggle>")
            .withProperty("leaf", item -> !getDataCommunicator().hasChildren(item))
            .withProperty("icon", item -> icon.getElement().getAttribute("icon"))
            .withProperty("style", item -> icon.getElement().getAttribute("style"))
            .withProperty("name", item -> String.valueOf(valueProvider.apply(item))));
        final SerializableComparator<T> comparator =  (a, b) ->
            compareMaybeComparables(valueProvider.apply(a), valueProvider.apply(b));
        column.setComparator(comparator);
        return column;
    }

}
```

Works like a charm.